# How do I figure out where a version is managed?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I've got a maven project A. This project depends on project B, which again depends on `mysql-connector-java`.

Project B depends on `mysql-connector-java:8.0.27`. However, no matter what I do project A insist on using `mysql-connector-java:5.1.39`.

Maven tells me :

> [INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile (version managed from 8.0.27)

Neither project A nor project B manage the version in any particular way, apart from the regular dependency inclusion which B does :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
```

How do I figure out where `mysql-connector-java` is managed? I've tried to search across the projects I manage - unable to find this specific version to be mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One way to analyze the dependencies a package has is by running the following command:
`mvn dependency:tree`

This will print a complete tree showing which dependency (and version) has been pulled into the project. This is a great way to see where the connector package with version 5.1.39 is coming from.

Once you find it, the best way to address it would be to uptick the package which is using the older version of the connector. Another (not the best) option would be to use an exclusion in package A's pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`, calling `mvn help:effective-pom` might also help to determine where it comes from.